# Script para Extrair Valores do site InfoMoney para Cotação de Dolar

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um Código PHP com um script em Jquery que coleta informações do site InfoMoney e retorna a cotação do dolar comercial (Compra e Venda).

Gostaria de saber como atualizar este código para que além dos valores de dolar comercial ele possa coletar os valores do dolar turismo, euro, etc.

Se alguém conseguir me ajudar com uma solução PHP ou Javascript seria muito bem vinda!

### Veja em funcionamento [clicando aqui](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/dm5i-wbs1)

**Código PHP**

```
<?php

  if(!$fp=fopen("https://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/cambio" , "r" )) 
  {
    echo "Erro ao abrir a página de cotação" ;
    exit;
  }

  $conteudo = '';
  while(!feof($fp)) 
  { 
    $conteudo .= fgets($fp,1024);
  }
  fclose($fp);

  $valorCompraHTML = explode('class="numbers">', $conteudo); 
  $valorCompra = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[5]));
  $valorVendaHTML = explode('+', strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[6]));

  //Estes são os valores HTML para exibir no site.  
  $valorVendaHTML = explode('-', $valorVendaHTML[0]);
  $valorVenda  = trim($valorVendaHTML[0]) ;

  //Estes são os valores numéricos para cálculos.     
  $valorCompraCalculavel = str_replace(',','.', $valorCompra);
  $valorVendaCalculavel  = str_replace(',','.', $valorVenda);

?>
```

**HTML e Javascript**

```
<p><strong>Compra:</strong> R$ <?php echo $valorCompra ?> <br/>
<strong>Venda:</strong> R$ <?php echo $valorVenda ?>  </p>


<h2>Exemplo de câmbio:</h2>
<label>Digite o valor em reais:</label>
<input type="text" id="converte" placeholder="1.00" onKeyUp="cambio()" style="width:50px">
<span id="resultado">0.00</span>    
<script>
    function cambio()
    {
        var valorDolarVenda = <?php echo $valorVendaCalculavel ?>;
        var valorReais   = document.getElementById('converte').value;
        if (document.getElementById('converte').value == '') valorReais = 0;
        var valorCambio = valorReais * valorDolarVenda;
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = valorCambio.toFixed(2);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os valores são pegos pelos elementos de class="numbers".   `$valorCompraHTML = explode('class="numbers">', $conteudo);`

Daí é só localizar no código fonte a posição, exemplo valor compra turismo   `valorCompraHTML[7]`.

```
<?php
if(!$fp=fopen("https://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/cambio" , "r" )) 
{
    echo "Erro ao abrir a página de cotação" ;
    exit;
}
$conteudo = '';
while(!feof($fp)) 
{ 
    $conteudo .= fgets($fp,1024);
}
fclose($fp);
$valorCompraHTML = explode('class="numbers">', $conteudo); 

$valorCompra = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[5]));

$valorVendaHTML = explode(' ', strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[6]));

//Estes são os valores HTML para exibir no site.    
$valorVendaHTML = explode(' ', $valorVendaHTML[0]);
$valorVenda  = trim($valorVendaHTML[0]) ;

//Compra Turismo.
$valorCompraT = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[7]));
$valorCompraT = explode(' ', $valorCompraT);
$valorCT  = trim($valorCompraT [0]) ;

//Venda Turismo.
$valorVendaT = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[8]));
$valorVendaT = explode(' ', $valorVendaT);
$valorVT  = trim($valorVendaT[0]) ;

//Compra Euro.
$valorCompraE = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[11]));
$valorCompraE = explode(' ', $valorCompraE);
$valorCE  = trim($valorCompraE[0]) ;

//Venda Euro.
$valorVendaE = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[12]));
$valorVendaE = explode(' ', $valorVendaE);
$valorVE  = trim($valorVendaE[0]) ;

//Estes são os valores numéricos para cálculos.   
$valorCompraCalculavel = str_replace(',','.', $valorCompra);
$valorVendaCalculavel  = str_replace(',','.', $valorVenda);
?> 
<html lan="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Simonetta" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>
            Exemplo de Script de cotação do dólar
        </title>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family: 'Simonetta', cursive;">
        <p>
            <strong>Compra:</strong>
            R$ 
            <?php echo $valorCompra ?> 
            <br/>
            <strong>Venda:</strong>
            R$ 
            <?php echo $valorVenda ?>  
        </p>
        <p>
            <strong>Turismo Compra:</strong>
            R$ 
            <?php echo $valorCT ?> 
            <br/>
            <strong>Turismo Venda:</strong>
            R$ 
            <?php echo $valorVT ?>  
        </p>
        <p>
            <strong>Euro Compra:</strong>
            R$ 
            <?php echo $valorCE ?> 
            <br/>
            <strong>Euro Venda:</strong>
            R$ 
            <?php echo $valorVE ?>  
        </p>
        <h2>
            Exemplo de câmbio:
        </h2>
        <label>Digite o valor em reais:</label>
        <input type="text" id="converte" placeholder="1.00" onKeyUp="cambio()" style="width:50px">
        <span id="resultado">0.00</span>
        <script>
            function cambio()
            {
                var valorDolarVenda = <?php echo $valorVendaCalculavel ?>;
                var valorReais   = document.getElementById('converte').value;
                if (document.getElementById('converte').value == '') valorReais = 0;
                var valorCambio = valorReais * valorDolarVenda;
                document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = valorCambio.toFixed(2);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

No PHP precisa atualizar esse código pois o site Infomoney mudou....

```
<?php

  if(!$fp=fopen("https://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/cambio" , "r" )) 
  {
    echo "Erro ao abrir a página de cotação" ;
    exit;
  }

  $conteudo = '';
  while(!feof($fp)) 
  { 
    $conteudo .= fgets($fp,1024);
  }
  fclose($fp);

  $valorCompraHTML = explode('<td><span>', $conteudo); 
  $valorCompra = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[1]));
  $valorVendaHTML = explode('+', strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[2]));

// Dolar comercial posicao 1 e 2
// Euro posicao 7 e 8
// Peso Argentino Posicao 13 e 14

  //Estes são os valores HTML para exibir no site.  
  $valorVendaHTML = explode('-', $valorVendaHTML[0]);
  $valorVenda  = trim($valorVendaHTML[0]) ;

  //Estes são os valores numéricos para cálculos.     
  $valorCompraCalculavel = str_replace(',','.', $valorCompra);
  $valorVendaCalculavel  = str_replace(',','.', $valorVenda);

?>
```