# Usando a função explode() no Infomoney

Tags: php

Estou tentando colocar alguns indicadores econômicos no site e arranjei um script que traz a cotação do dolar à partir do site do Infomoney.

Pore´m estou querendo outros índices, mas o resultado do campo é composto e separado por espaços. O código ficou assim:

```
if(!$fp=fopen("https://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/acoes-e-indices" , "r" )) 
{
    echo "Erro ao abrir a página de indices" ;
    exit;
}
$conteudo = '';
while(!feof($fp)) 
{ 
    $conteudo .= fgets($fp,1024);
}
fclose($fp);

$valorCompraHTML    = explode('class="numbers">', $conteudo); 
// Esta é a variável que eu preciso explodir
$campo5             = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[5]));

//Estes são os valores HTML para exibir no site.    
$ibovespa = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[5]));
$ibovespa = explode(' ', $ibovespa);
$bovespa  = trim($ibovespa[0]) ;
```

O campo sem explodir está assim: 74.294 +0,99 e no resultado desta variável está vindo apenas 74.294.

Eu precisava saber como faz para retornar o segundo valor, o +0,99

Comment: Ué, ao invés de 0 coloca 1.

Comment: Tentei fazer isso mas retorna campo vazio...

Comment: Se alguma resposta lhe for útil não deixe de marcá-la como aceita, veja aqui o porque https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem várias formas de se obter o desejado, mas vou me ater a respostas que vão ao encontro da dificuldade postulada na pergunta.

O valor é pego pelo elemento de class="numbers positivo"

**PHP**

```
if(!$fp=fopen("https://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/acoes-e-indices" , "r" )) 
{
    echo "Erro ao abrir a página de indices" ;
    exit;
}
$conteudo = '';
while(!feof($fp)) 
{ 
    $conteudo .= fgets($fp,1024);
}
fclose($fp);

$valorCompraHTML    = explode('class="numbers">', $conteudo); 
$ibovespa = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[5]));
$ibovespa = explode(' ', $ibovespa);
$bovespa  = trim($ibovespa[0]);

$valorMais    = explode('class="numbers positivo">', $conteudo); 
$mais = trim(strip_tags($valorMais[1]));
$mais = explode(' ', $mais);
$maisResult  = trim($mais[0]);
```

**HTML**

```
R$  <?php echo $bovespa  ?>  <?php echo $maisResult ?>
```

---

**Outra forma de obter o mesmo resultado**

Conforme dito na pergunta do autor `O campo sem explodir está assim: 74.294 +0,99` não corresponde a realidade, na verdade o campo retorna assim,

[image: campo]

portanto devemos retirar todos os espaços extras antes do explode para ficar assim `74.294 +0,99`

```
if(!$fp=fopen("https://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/acoes-e-indices" , "r" )) 
{
    echo "Erro ao abrir a página de indices" ;
    exit;
}
$conteudo = '';
while(!feof($fp)) 
{ 
    $conteudo .= fgets($fp,1024);
}
fclose($fp);

$valorCompraHTML    = explode('class="numbers">', $conteudo); 
// Esta é a variável que eu preciso explodir
$campo5             = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[5]));

//Estes são os valores HTML para exibir no site.    
$ibovespa = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[5]));

//retira todos os espaços em branco e retorna 74.294 +0,99
$ibovespa = preg_replace(array("/\t/", "/\s{2,}/", "/\n/", "/\r/"), array("", " ", " ", " "), $ibovespa);

$ibovespa = explode(' ', $ibovespa);

$bovespa  = trim($ibovespa[0]);

$mais  = trim($ibovespa[1]);
```

[script para Dolar, euro etc...](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210299/script-para-extrair-valores-do-site-infomoney-para-cota%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-dolar/210344#210344)

---

---

O **explode()** foi criado com a intenção de separar uma string em um array de várias strings menores. Para isto ele utiliza determinados caracteres, passados por parâmetros, para fazer a separação.

Na programação, a **gambiarra** é uma maneira paliativa (e criativa) de resolver um problema ou corrigir um sistema de forma ineficiente, deselegante ou incompreensível, mas que mesmo assim funciona.

Este é um código que imprime na tela a repetição da frase "Hello world!" 5 vezes utilizando-se para isto de um laço para controlar

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("Hello world!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Este é um código que imprime na tela a repetição da frase "Hello world" 5 vezes, porém utilizando-se de gambiarra para obter o resultado final:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    printf("Hello world!");
    printf("Hello world!");
    printf("Hello world!");
    printf("Hello world!");
    printf("Hello world!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sensacional, agora deu certo. Eu nunca iria descobrir isso sozinho. Obrigado irmão!

Answer (score 2):

Utilizar `explode` para tratar e encontrar HTML, sendo que o PHP tem recursos nativos para isso... Por mim é uma enorme gambiarra.

Você pode utilizar o XPath (ou outro recurso), para localizar tal elemento diretamente. O número está dentro de um `td` com a classe `positivo` ou `negativo`, além disso esta tabela está dentro de uma `div` com id de `pnlContentA`.

Portanto bastaria fazer:

```
//div[contains(@id, "pnlContentA")]//td[contains(@class,"numbers") and (contains(@class, "positivo") or contains(@class, "negativo"))]
```

No caso do PHP:

```
$Numbers = $XPath->query('
//div[contains(@id, "pnlContentA")]
//td[contains(@class,"numbers") and (contains(@class, "positivo") or contains(@class, "negativo"))]
');
```

*Você pode testar o XPath acima no próprio Chrome, no console em "Elementos" e depois um "Ctrl + F" e colando o XPath acima.*

---

No final teria algo deste tipo:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$ch = curl_init('http://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/acoes-e-indices');
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => 1,
    CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTP,
]);

$conteudo = curl_exec($ch); 

if($conteudo !== false) {
    $DOM = new DOMDocument();
    $DOM->loadHTML($conteudo);

    $XPath = new DOMXPath($DOM);

    $Numbers = $XPath->query('
    //div[contains(@id, "pnlContentA")]
    //td[contains(@class,"numbers") and (contains(@class, "positivo") or contains(@class, "negativo"))]
    ');

    foreach ($Numbers as $number){
        echo htmlentities($number->nodeValue, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
        echo '<br>';
    }

}
```

O cURL fará a requisição e retornará o corpo da página, ou falhará imediatamente. Então, criamos o DOM e importamos o HTML, usando o `$DOM->loadHTML($conteudo)`.

Agora a parte principal, localizamos a `div` que contenha um *id* de `pnlContentA`, depois localizamos um `td` dentro dele que tenha a classe de `Numbers` e também que tenha a classe de `positivo` ou `negativo`.

Isso dá como resultado:

```
+0,99
+1,05
+1,00
+1,67
+1,20
+1,47
+1,34
+2,12
+0,80
+1,01
+1,43
+0,97
+1,93
```

---

*Este site é inseguro, não possui HTTPS, a conexão é redirecionada sempre para HTTP. Devido a isto nem fiz questão de utilizar qualquer recurso do cURL.*

Comment: +1 ... PS: não é questão só de gambiarra, é questão de manutenção ou melhor dizendo, pra que usar explode se existem funções com este propósito. :D

Comment: é verdade, mas daí a pergunta deveria ser outra "Qual a melhor forma ...."

Answer (score 0):

Se o campo está vindo 74.294 +0,99 e você criou um Array com `explode()`:

```
$ibovespa = explode(' ', $ibovespa);
```

Os elementos dessa Array serão:

```
ibovespa[0] = "74.294"
ibovespa[1] = "+0,99"
```

**Logo**, para pegar o segundo valor (segundo elemento da Array), basta usar o código:

```
$bovespa2  = trim($ibovespa[1]);
```

Comment: Foi o que eu pensei. Estou usando assim:                          $valorVendaHTML  = explode('+', strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[5]));
//Estes são os valores HTML para exibir no site. 
$ibovespa = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[5]));
$ibovespa = explode(' ', $ibovespa);
$bovespa  = trim($ibovespa[1]) ;       Mas está retornando campo vazio

Comment: Aqui tá vindo o valor correto. Dá uma olhada neste Ideone: https://ideone.com/S56u4K